# using akka jar files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, akka

I want know is it possible to create akka actor

in eclipse java projects by importing

the akka jar files.

can anyone tell how it can be done.

for example first create a new project in eclipse and then

create an akka actor object or class in the projecct

it it is not possible are there other alternatives of

for creating akka actors in eclipse java projects

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple example. 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [Akka Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/)